# Error with lidR::normalize_height

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I am making a code for my master's thesis, in a part of the code I seek to obtain the normalization of the DSM of some municipalities of Galicia. The LiDAR files used come from the CNIG, they are the data from the 2nd coverage (2015-current), the DTM data also come from the CNIG and they are the data with a mesh step of 2x2. The LiDAR information by municipalities is very heavy and I have had to carry out the reading of the .las files in parts.
After reading the files I calculate the DSM with the following function:

```r
DSM_estrada_1 <- lidR::grid_canopy(LiDARfiles_estrada_1, res = 2, algorithm = lidR::p2r(subcircle = 1, na.fill = tin()))
```

This first step works perfectly on any of the selected data, the problem arises when normalizing.

When performing the function for any of the selected municipalities I get the following error:

```
LiDARNorm <- lidR::normalize_height(LiDARfiles_estrada_1, InpDTM, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Error: On-disk rasters not supported in 'raster_as_dataframe()'
#> In addition: Warning message:
#> In raster_cell_from_xy(raster, x, y) :
#> NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

The issue is that in some municipalities it works for me and in others I get that error. I can't find a possible solution anywhere.

Comment: I send LiDAR and DTM data compressed in a link to google drive (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XnwjLlg67Ik4p7fpcwqzZGXPYdPfptAP?usp=sharing). This would be the code that I use to read the files and perform the normalization of the data:

Comment: InpDTM <-mosaic(dtm_120_4,dtm_121_2,dtm_121_3,dtm_122_1,dtm_122_4,dtm_123_1, dtm_123_3,dtm_153_1, fun=mean, tolerance=0.5)                                         InpDTM <- focal( InpDTM  , w = matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3), fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE, NAonly = TRUE)
crs(InpDTM) <- "+proj=utm +zone=29 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"  LiDAR_estrada_1 <- "C:/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXX/estrada_1" # Directorio LiDAR
LiDARfiles_estrada_1 <- lidR::catalog(LiDAR_estrada_1)
LiDARfiles_estrada_1 <- lidR::readLAS(LiDARfiles_estrada_1) LiDARNorm <- lidR::normalize_height(LiDARfiles_estrada_1, InpDTM, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: Solucionado. Demasiados archivos LiDAR juntos. De 2 en 2 o de 4 en 4 si funciona.
Gracias

Comment: This error looks internal to the function. Have you contacted the developer or submitted a bug on the GitHub development site (https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR)? The current development build is failing but, you may want to try installing as soon as it is stable.